# What is the difference between object detection and target detection? Are they the same thing?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, signal-detection, detection, object-detection

I was reading some articles regarding object detection and target detection and have a hard time understanding the difference between object detection and target detection. i want to know whether they are different from each other? and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

"Target" is a military term; historically, that's why it's the word used for "identifiable thing from a radar system".

So, I wouldn't use "target detection" outside of radar systems, whereas the word "object detection" is generally used in image processing (for anything that isn't a person). I might be a bit alone with this, but if I look at an image and someone asks me to perform "target detection" on that, I'd assume they want to *shoot* at that.

I think "target" in radar has a more "physical meaning", as in, it's actually a single contiguous physical object which emits/reflects radio-frequency emissions that should be recognized / tracked as such.

"Object" can be anything, from a round ball, to scattered remnants of a white blood cell; it's slightly less "physical", more "appearance-based".  (Of course, reflecting light is still reflecting EM waves; the difference lies in the number of sensor elements in a camera vs radar array.)